# Entering in Command Line Arguments MIPS

Tags: macos, bash, mips, qtspim

I am trying to run a MIPS program and I need to enter in command line arguments. I am having issues doing this on my computer. I have installed QTSpim and tried typing "spim -f program.s arg1 arg2" into the mac terminal like we do in class, but I am getting the error "-bash: spim: command not found". I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: On what path did you install the binaries of the emulator ?

That path needs to be in your PATH of your shell ...

Comment: I am rather new to this sort of thing....So I don't really know what that means. I installed it following the instructions on the website

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is always the name of the program. so your first argument its actually the second one.