# How do you enter command line arguments in SPIM

Tags: assembly, command-line, mips, spim

I am trying to make programs using `argc` and `argv` in MIPS simulator SPIM.
This is my code:

```
.data
nl: .asciiz "\n"

.globl main
.text
main:
  # print argv[0]
  lw $a0, 0($a1)
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
  # print "\n"
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, nl
  syscall
  # exit
  li $v0, 10
  syscall
```

When I run

```
$ spim -f args.s
Loaded: /usr/share/spim/exceptions.s                                                                    
args.s
```

I get the correct result `argv[0]` (the name of the program). But if I try

```
$ spim -f args.s hello
Loaded: /usr/share/spim/exceptions.s
Cannot open file: `(null)'
Memory address out of bounds
```

I get that error. I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything. What's the correct way to pass arguments to `argv[]`?
Changing the `lw` in the code to `lw $a0, 4($a1)` gets me the following output.

```
$ spim -f args.s hello
Loaded: /usr/share/spim/exceptions.s
Cannot open file: `(null)'
SHELL=/bin/zsh
```

I tried in the virtual console and it's the same. After printing all the environment variables changing the offset in the `lw` it justs prints "Memory address out of bounds".

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to do this running spim from the command line.  I run QtSpim interactively, which offers a menu item "Simulator" -> "Run Parameters", where you can type the rest of the command line for the simulated program.  They appear in `argc`/`argv` (following the program name in `argv[0]`) as you'd expect.

Comment: [Entering in Command Line Arguments MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35997741) is a *possible* duplicate.  The question looks like an install error, but the answer is answering the title (not body) and suggests  that the first arg goes as `argv[0]` (traditionally the program name), not `argv[1]` (the first actual arg).  No idea if it's true.

Comment: I saw that question, but it's not the same as this one. Maybe I am doing it correctly but something is wrong with my installation. I'm using Arch Linux and installed SPIM from the AUR.

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved it. The right way to use program arguments is indeed

```
$ spim -f code.s arg1 arg2 etc
```

Turns out I was wrong when I said that I installed it from the AUR, I compiled it from source using the last snapshot on the official Sourceforge repo.
There is a bug in `spim.cpp`. After line 278 it should say `break;` and it works flawlessly. I already created a ticket in Sourceforge so they can patch it.